# Заменить даты в dataframe на последовательную нумерацию с условием

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Всем привет!

Нужно в столбце "date" заменить даты на последовательную нумерацию, с условием, что если в столбце "skv" меняется значение, то нумерация начинается снова с цифры 1.

```
from ast import parse
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl
import numpy
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep = ';')
result = pd.read_csv('result.csv', sep=';') 
result1 = pd.read_csv('result1.csv')
data_result = pd.pivot_table(data, index=['skv','date', 'diaphragm'])
df = data_result.reset_index()
date = list(df['date'])
codes, uniques = pd.factorize(df['date'])
df['date'] = codes + 1
```

Есть такой фрагмент кода, который преобразует даты в нумерацию
Помогите пожалуйста дописать или переписать код, так, чтобы нумерация начиналась сначала при смене значения в столбце "skv"

Должно получится примерно так.
[image: Должно получится примерно так]

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверняка можно короче, но я придумал только так:

```
import pandas as pd

# пример данных, чтобы код можно было запустить с ними
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6], 
                   'skv': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002]})

# собственно код с логикой
# берём минимум по каждому skv
min_date = df.groupby(['skv']).min().reset_index()
# присоединяем этот минимум к датафрейму
df = pd.merge(df, min_date, on='skv', suffixes=['','_min'])
# вычитаем минимум, прибавляем 1 - получаем счёт от 1
df['date'] = df['date'] - df['date_min'] + 1
# выкидываем не нужную теперь колонку
df = df.drop(columns='date_min')
df
```

Вывод:

```
   date skv
0   1   1001
1   1   1001
2   2   1001
3   2   1001
4   3   1001
5   4   1001
6   1   1002
7   1   1002
8   2   1002
9   3   1002
10  3   1002
```

Comment: А если таблица гораздо больше, и значений в тысячи раз больше?)
Я просто привел здесь небольшой обрывок таблицы

Comment: @Egor1996 Я просто привёл пример кода с данными, который можно скопировать и попробовать запустить. Вы же не привели в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных. Я же не буду с картинки данные набивать, правильно? Код должен и с вашими данными работать, пусть там и миллионы строк, какие проблемы?

Comment: Сейчас попробовал с миллионом случайных строк - отрабатывает за 0.1с; а если 10 миллионов, то за 2.5с

Comment: Понял, буду пробовать, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Добавил комментариев в код

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Отметьте потом ответ как правильный, кажется, это не сразу можно сделать )

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с помощью [`rank()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': list(range(26,29))*4,'skv': [1101]*4 + [1102]*8}).sort_values(['skv','date'])
df['№ в группе'] = df.groupby(['skv']).rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print(df)
```

```
    date   skv  № в группе
0     26  1101           1
3     26  1101           1
1     27  1101           2
2     28  1101           3
6     26  1102           1
9     26  1102           1
4     27  1102           2
7     27  1102           2
10    27  1102           2
5     28  1102           3
8     28  1102           3
11    28  1102           3
```

Comment: У автора вопроса повторы в этой цифре есть, так что не совсем такая нумерация, если я правильно понимаю

Comment: @CrazyElf нумерацию сделал подобно примеру автора вопроса. Повторы обрабатываются корректно с параметром `dense`.

Comment: А, ну отлично. Просто у вас в примере не было повторов.